# react-bootstrap button on same line as text field

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap, how to keep the button in the same line of my text field?

[image]

```
            <FormGroup>
                <InputGroup >
                    <FormControl
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Search for artist"
                    />
                    <InputGroup.Append> 
                     <Button><Octicon  name="search"/></Button>
                    </InputGroup.Append>
                </InputGroup>
            </FormGroup>
```

Comment: Adding a class to the InputGroup and then on the css write that class as `display: flex;` https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp ?

Comment: @fedeteka it worked, please make answer to mark correct, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a class to the InputGroup and then on the css write that class as

```
display: flex;
```

w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp